# NSTextField stringvalue not setting correctly in ViewController.cs

Tags: xamarin.mac

Trying to get into Xamarin Mac dev, and I think i'm missing a scoping thing. In the AppDelegate.cs, in the main app namespace, I have a string defined:

```
namespace Test
{

    //Application Variables

    public class appProperties
    {
        public static string localHostName = "";
    }
```

and in the DidFinishLaunching function, I run scutil --get LocalHostName:

```
    Process scutilTest = new Process();
    scutilTest.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    scutilTest.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    scutilTest.StartInfo.FileName = "/usr/sbin/scutil";
    scutilTest.StartInfo.Arguments = " --get LocalHostName";
    scutilTest.Start();

    appProperties.localHostName = scutilTest.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    scutilTest.WaitForExit();
```

If I pop an alert with appProperties.localHostName in the AppDelegate.cs file, it displays correctly.

But in in my ViewController.cs file, in the ViewDidLoad() function, when I try to set the StringValue of an NSTextField lable to appProperties.localHostName, nothing shows up:

```
theCurrentLocalHostName.StringValue = appProperties.localHostName;
```

fails to set the StringValue. If i set that to a hardcoded string, i.e. "look at me", that works fine. I know this is simple, but googling has not pointed me at why this isn't working. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hard to say for sure without complete code. Try setting an initial value.
public static string localHostName = "Test"; Maybe the process code has not run yet?

Comment: i beat on it a bit, it looks like it has to be in the viewdidload() function to work.